# Remove a repetitive line when creating a data frame using a "for" loop

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the number of complete rows (no NA values) in a bunch of CSV files. Every time I add a new line to my data frame using my for loop though, it outputs how I created that new line above the row. How do I stop this from happening/delete the repetitive label?

I have tried using removeWords and stop words.

```
complete <- function(directory, site.id = 1:332) {
  for (i in site.id) {
    path <- paste(getwd(), "/", directory, "/", sprintf("%03d", i), ".csv", sep = "")
    dat <- read.csv(path)
    DF <- data.frame(sum(!complete.cases(dat)), row.names = i)
    print(DF)
  }

}
```

I want the results to look like this:

```
1    1344
2    2611
3    1948
```

But they inevitably end up looking like this:

```
  sum..complete.cases.dat..
1                      1344
  sum..complete.cases.dat..
2                      2611
  sum..complete.cases.dat..
3                      1948
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the dataframe outside the loop. By doing it inside the loop you are creating a dataframe that only exists for that iteration of the loop doesn't store the values together, permanently.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c())
```

Then when you add each element, direct it to the index of first column and ith row. The row names will automatically count up.

```
df[i,1] <- sum(!complete.cases(dat))
```

So it would look like:

```
df[i,1] <- sum(!complete.cases(dat))

complete <- function(directory, site.id = 1:332) {
  for (i in site.id) {
    path <- paste(getwd(), "/", directory, "/", sprintf("%03d", i), ".csv", sep = "")
    dat <- read.csv(path)
    df[i,1] <- sum(!complete.cases(dat))
    print(DF)
  }
}
```

Comment: Solved! One tiny tweak for anyone reading this in the future though: you need to initialize the data frame outside the loop using the first thing cparmstrong wrote, ie
"df <- data.frame(id = c())". Also, for the results that I wanted to obtain, the 1 and the i in the dataframe brackets needs to be switched.

Comment: Sorry about that @montyman14 you're right, I inverted the row and column indices. Row goes first then column.